# Spectrum of Laplacian on Half line. $\left [0, \infty \right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I would like to calculate the spectrum of Dirichlet and Neumann Laplacian of the domain $\left [0,\infty \right)$.

To be precise, Define the Operator
$T$ on $L^2\left[0,\infty\right)$ as $Tf=-f''$ and $D(T)=H^2\cap H_0^1$.

And
$S$ on $L^2\left[0,\infty\right)$ as $Sf=-f''$ and $D(T)=H^2 \cap \left \{f\in H^2 | f'(0)=0 \right \}$.

Find out the Spectrum of T and S.

Here T is Dirichlet Laplacian and S is Neumann Laplacian.

Answer (score 5):

The operators $S$ and $T$ and selfadjoint on their respective domains. These have to do with even and odd extensions. An even extension of $f \in \mathcal{D}(S)$ is in $H^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, and an odd extension of $f \in \mathcal{D}(T)$ is in $H^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.
So the operators $S$ and $T$ can be expressed in terms of the Fourier cosine and sine transforms:
$$
   Sf = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{2}\cos(sx)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\cos(st)dt\,ds,\\
   Tf = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}s^{2}\sin(sx)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\sin(st)dt\,ds.
$$
Both have spectrum $[0,\infty)$ with resolvents
$$
  (S-\lambda I)^{-1}f = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{s^{2}-\lambda}\cos(sx)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\cos(st)dt\,ds,\\
  (T-\lambda I)^{-1}f = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{s^{2}-\lambda}\sin(sx)\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\sin(st)dt\,ds.
$$

Comment: I cannot understand why this answer has been downvoted.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro : Thanks for your support. The person who posted the question didn't accept the truth of the answer either. :) I'm frankly baffled that such classical, well-understood Mathematics is treated with suspicion.

Comment: @T.A.E. My Sincere Apologies sir, I say nothing in my defense. Actually I myself dont remember why I down voted it

Comment: @Harish : Okay. If you have a question about this, I can help. You can derive these expansions directly from the resolvent operator, too, which can be written in terms of the Green function. The resolvent ends up analytic everywhere except for the positive real axis where there is a branch cut. The resolvent is then reduced to an integral over $[0,\infty)$ where the integrand is the jump in the resolvent function across the branch cut. A change of variable to get rid of the square root in the integration variable then gives you the above. That's the direct resolvent method; the end is the same

Comment: Do you have any reference for this information?

Comment: @wroobell : Are you wanting to know more about the Fourier cosine and sine transforms, more about the fact that the operators $S$ and $T$ are selfadjoint, or something else?

Comment: @wroobell : I noticed missing $ds$ and a wrong outer integration limit. Typos, and I just fixed them.

Comment: I am generally interested in laplacian on half line. Self-adjointness is quite obviuos, but i would like to know hon to prove that spectrum is $[0, \infty)$ and possibly know something about spectral measures.

Comment: The deriviation of integral formulas of operators would be nice to. All in all, my goal is to study fractional laplacian on a half line and i am looking for possible new ways to define it.

Comment: Start by constructing the resolvent of $T_0$. There is a constant $C$ such that $$C(T-\lambda I)^{-1}f = e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}t)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}f(t)+\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\int_{x}^{\infty}f(t)  e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}t}dt$$

Comment: @wroobell : After you construct the resolvent as above, you find that the resolvent is bounded everywhere except $\lambda\in[0,\infty)$. The jump in the resolvent across the real axis gives you the spectral representation, and the spectral density, and the integral of that jump over $[0,\infty)$ times $1/2\pi$ (from Cauchy integral) is the spectral resolution of the identity. That's a general principle that follows from Stone's Formula for Spectral Measures. Post a question if you want more information.

Comment: I only have rudimentary knowledge about spectral theory, mainly for bounded operators. Thought you might know about any source where the case of operators $T,S$ is accesibly covered. I will have to study further about unbounded operator spectral theory. Any textbook recomendations?

Comment: @wroobell : The Green function I gave you can be easily verified to define a resolvent for $\lambda\notin[0,\infty)$. There's nothing more straightforward than constructing the resolvent and deducing the spectrum. The $C$ is related to the Wronskian of $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}t)$ and $e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}t}$. The sin satisfies the left endpoint condition, and $e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x}$ is square integrable near $\infty$. That's what you need. If you want references for this particular topic, I find classical results to be almost missing from standard references or made inaccessible by abstraction.