# Discrete and Essential spectrum of Laplacian in $\mathbb R_{+}$ (with weird boundary conditions)

Tags: analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am given

on Hilbert Space $\mathcal H=L^2(\mathbb R_{+})$

$$
Af(x)=-f''(x)
$$
 and

Domain of A is 
$$
D(A)=\{f\in H_2(\mathbb R_{+})\;\;| \;\;f'(0)+\alpha f(0)=0\}
$$

for some $\alpha \in \mathbb R$

I need to find discrete and essential spectrum of this unbounded operator. I only know one way of finding the spectrum of Laplacian, that is by Fourier transform (and its variant for half line). I do not know how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the operator 
$$
A_0f(x)=-f''(x)
$$

$$
D(A_0)=\{f\in H_2(\mathbb R_{+})\;\;| \;\;f'(0)=f(0)=0\}
$$

It is a symmetric operator with (finite and equal) defect indices $(1,1)$. All self-adjoint extensions (including operator $A$ depending on $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, and the one with '$\alpha=\infty$', which corresponds to the boundary condition $f(0)=0$) have the same essential spectrum. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138321/spectrum-of-laplacian-on-half-line-left-0-infty-right) question it is shown that this spectrum is $[0,\infty)$.

Assume that $A$ has a point spectrum, i.e. $Af=-f''=\lambda f,\ \lambda\in\mathbb R$. The fundamental solution of $f''+\lambda f=0$ is either $$\{\sin{\sqrt{\lambda}x},\ \cos{\sqrt{\lambda}x}\},\ \lambda>0$$ or $$\{e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x},e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}\},\ \lambda<0$$ or $$\{1,x\},\ \lambda=0.$$

Since $f\in H_2(\mathbb R_{+})$, the only possible eigenvector of $A$ is $e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$ for $\lambda <0$. The boundary condition $f'(0)+\alpha f(0)=0$ implies 
$$-\sqrt{-\lambda}e^{0}+\alpha e^{0}=0$$ i.e. $\alpha=-\sqrt{-\lambda},\ \lambda<0$.

Hence, $A$ has a point spectrum iff $\alpha<0$. In this case $\sigma_p(A)=\{-\alpha^2\}.$

Comment: do you mean to say the operator given in the question has self adjoint extension which is Dirichelet Laplacian? I am not familiar with the term "defect" and "defect indices". It would be to me if you could elaborate. Thanks

Comment: No, I mean that for every $\alpha,$ $A$ is a self-adjoint extension of the symmetric operator $A_0$. Note, that $A_0$ is not a Dirichlet or Neumann Laplacian.

Comment: The operator $A$ depends on $\alpha$. But given symmetric operator can have only one Self Adjoint extension. But we shall have different operator $A$ for different values if $\alpha$ @Yurii Savchuk

Comment: A given symmetric operator (e.g. $A_0$) has usually a continuous family of s.a. extensions!

Comment: Thank you, can you give me references where I can see why self adjoint extensions of an operator share same essential spectrum with original operator. And references for the terminology "defects " and "defect indices" @Yurii Savchuk

Comment: I have just found one reference: N.i.Akhiezer, I.M.Glazman "Theory of linear operators in Hilbert space" Vol. 2, Chapter VII, §83. In the previous chapters the deficiency indices are defined.

Comment: These are also called "mixed boundary conditions" or "Robin boundary conditions."